# ERR_ABORTED 415 (Unsupported Media Type) on fetch API - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

> I'm trying to make a POST request to an API REST, but i get this error (ERR_ABORTED 415 (Unsupported Media Type)) on this code:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('https://volgarest.herokuapp.com/volga-rest/shops/log-up/', {
        method : 'POST',
        body : JSON.stringify(this.state),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
        },
        mode : 'no-cors'            
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
};
```